# applescript: work "whose" and "exists" into the same line

Tags: error-handling, applescript

My problem can best be demonstrated with one line of code:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Dock" ¬
to tell list 1 to first UI element whose value of attribute "AXTitle" ¬
is "Trash"
```

This ends in error because not every `UI element` in Dock has `attribute "AXTitle"`. `dock separator item` only has `AXRole`, `AXRoleDescription`, etc.

**I want to know** if there is a way to have the code return the correct `UI element` despite this.

Here is what I've tried and failed:

1) **try block**: This simply jump over this line of code and continue to next line

2) **ignore application response block**: Ditto.

3) **exists(attribute "attributeName")**: I was able to test each individual `UI element` with e.g. `exists (attribute "AXTitle") of UI element 1`, but I cannot works `exists` into `whose` statement: It should look something like this:

```
UI elements whose (exists (attribute "AXTitle") is true)
```

And that doesn't work. Right now I have to run a `repeat with` loop, a `if` statement inside, and an `exit repeat` so that I can cycle through everything. This is cumbersome.

There has to be a better way.

**Clarification**: A few people showed me more elegant ways to get to `Trash`. I used `Trash` as an example but meant the question to be broarder, namely **how to find the first item of a list based on an attribute when a item in the list lacks this atrribute**. Another example would be:

```
delay 5
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Dock" ¬
to tell list 1 to first UI element whose value of attribute ¬
"AXSelected" is true
```

And move cursor to any item in the Dock. This example failed because again `Dock Separator` doesn't have the common field "AXSelected".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another condition like this : `whose subrole is not "AXSeparatorDockItem"`

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Dock" to tell list 1 to (first UI element whose subrole is not "AXSeparatorDockItem" and its selected is true)
end tell
```

--

**Update** : You can use the `title` property instead of `value of attribute "AXTitle"`, this will not give error.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Dock" to tell list 1 to UI elements whose title is "Trash"
end tell
```

Comment: This is the best solution I've seen, though I do wish I can add a condition like `whose attribute "attributeName" exists`. It's the same thing with cycling through menu items when there's a separator.

Comment: It's not possible to use the `exists` command.  I add another solution to my answer

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, and is also better, since the title of the "Trash" is localized, here it is "Papirkurv". :)

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Dock"
    tell list 1
        get first UI element whose value of attribute "AXSubrole" is "AXTrashDockItem"
    end tell
end tell
```

If you got Xcode installed, then you should have an app named `UIElementInspector`, which lets you read off the different values of the UI Elements.

Comment: Thanks. I meant the question to be about cycling through an attribute even some items lack this attribute. The attribute I really really want is `AXSelected`.  Dock separator doesn't have it. I thought I'd use `Trash` so people don't have to `delay` and move cursor to test. Oops.

Comment: I think, that it is a no can do with a whose clause, as long as the filte will err when it meets items that doesn't have the property. I guess you'll have to get a list of items that has the selected property first, -building it with  a repeat loop, and then loop through it again, to finde the one which has AXSelected = true.